# UWP saving toggle switch state on navigation view

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, uwp-xaml

So I have a navigation view and a settingspage.xaml.
My mainwindow.xaml looks like this:

```xml
<NavigationView 
            PaneDisplayMode="LeftCompact"
            IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed"
            SelectionChanged="NavigationView_SelectionChanged"
            Loaded="NavigationView_Loaded"
            IsSettingsVisible="True">

            <NavigationView.MenuItems>

                <NavigationViewItem Content="Player" Icon="Microphone" Tag="playerview"/>
                <NavigationViewItem Content="About" Icon="Contact" Tag="aboutview"/>

            </NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <ScrollViewer>
                <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" />
            </ScrollViewer>
</NavigationView>
```

And the cs file is just navigating between pages.

Here is my SettingsPage.xaml

```xml
<Grid>
        <StackPanel Margin="40,40,20,40">
            
            <TextBlock Text="Settings" FontSize="20" />
            <ToggleSwitch Margin="0,25,0,0" x:Name="SwitchPresence" Header="Discord Presence" Toggled="ToggleSwitch_Toggled"/>
            
        </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

It works fine, but whenever I navigate to other pages and navigate back to the settings page, the current state is off even tho I on it.

Comment: Any updates about your issue?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the behavior is that UWP won't cache the Page object. So when you navigate back to the SettingsPage, your app will create a new SettingsPage instance.

To save the toggle button value, the simplest way is to enable the [NavigationCacheMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.navigationcachemode?view=winrt-19041) of the Page class. When you enabled this property, the SettingsPage will be cached and you will see the toggle button value is not reset.

If you need to access this value on other pages, then I'd suggest you save the toggle button value inside your App class directly or save it in a singleton class that used as a data manager.